# how can i perform a headless authentication with Azure AD+Pingfederate

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, adal, azure-ad-msal, pingfederate

My Azure AD sync from my on-premise AD with Azure AD connect without password hash sync. And i use Pingfederate as Identity Provider through SAML. That is, when i log in my web app registered in Azure AD, i will be redirected to login.microsoft.com/xxx, after i submit my username, i will be redirected to Pingfederate login page and input my password to finish the authentication.

Now i have a situation, i need to finish this authentication in a programmatic way. if i use ADAL or MSAL, Could i get an access token from Azure with my username and password in my request without interactive log-in? Is there any experience?

I konw it is workable that finish this authentication if there is just AAD or password hash sync is active. But i have no idea about Azure AD+Pingfederate.Because the authentication is finished in Pingfederate not AAD.

Answer (score 0):

[ADAL will try to use WS-Trust](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samueld/2015/06/05/office-modern-auth-adfs-making-it-work/) to your Ping and then use the resulting SAML response with AAD. Using username/pwd in the request assumes that your Ping is not using 2nd FA.